# How to fix TypeError Failed to fetch error in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have written API which adds the URL in Ingress controller. At the end of executing the code, I want to check, whether URL is working or not by checking the HTTP status code.

Here is the code:

```
int responseCode = 0;
while (responseCode != 200) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://" + tenantURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
        Thread.sleep(45000);
        System.out.println("still waiting....");
    }
}
```

However, getting error:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

what is the issue in the code?

Comment: You haven't shown us enough information. The error message you include is likely a JavaScript error, yet you haven't shown any details of any JS you are running. Please edit your question to include the details of how your JS code is calling your Java code, and additionally any extra error messages you can see in your browser's developer tools.